# How to check if GcmBroadcastReceiver is running?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

My app was working fine and was receiving push notifications, today I added some new layout and also change some other activity. But Now the app is not receiving any push notifications. I installed the old apk and tested, and still its not receiving any Push notifications.

So, Registered the device again with new IDs, and when i checked the Gcm manifest its shows :

```
{"multicast_id":7626883831612562770,"success":2,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1410175055111515%ae2db952f9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1410175055111884%ae2db952f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

Both are newly registered ID's, but its still not working.

LogCat for the App :

```
09-08 16:44:58.360    7151-7244/in.wirefreeworld.wfw D/111﹕ Device registered, registration ID=APA91bF3BhiliA8Xrtkh7HfUSHlpq9UrkhbAkIPY_poWjWBcAlgnIkF2Hbd38KakR43fucTxfHOcCH4zfyLEd7Q2uLRZIupMD-erk4gUoSpX2rk1YbMIDHLIZ7cFopHUdJ8ocLQM4X2hDajLml0vJVvp4M9hodKecw
09-08 16:44:58.490    7151-7172/in.wirefreeworld.wfw D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1322K, 8% free 15664K/17016K, paused 23ms, total 25ms
09-08 16:44:58.880    7151-7151/in.wirefreeworld.wfw D/Volley﹕ [1] 4.onResponse: MainActivity
```

GcmBroadcastReceiver.java Class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

GCMNotificationIntentService.java

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "GCMNotificationIntentService";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                        + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                            "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "
                                    + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }

                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                sendNotification("New Product: "
                        + extras.get(Config.MESSAGE_KEY));
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif);
                mBuilder.setTicker("Wire Free World");
                mBuilder.setContentTitle("Wire Free World");
                mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg));
                mBuilder.setContentText(msg);
                long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500};
                mBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            if(alarmSound == null){
                alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
            }
        mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
        wl.acquire(5000);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.listviewfeed"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.listviewfeed.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.listviewfeed.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notif"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".product"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_product"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="info.androidhive.listviewfeed" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />
    </application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</manifest>
```